# Parallel cosine distance using clusterapply in R

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I need to calculate cosine distance similarity between a vector and large matrix (>1000000 rows). Code is below. It works correctly but I do not see 100% utilization of my 8 core machine (nothing else is running on it) and overall speed up over linear version of "cosine(vecA, matB)" is quite low.

Is there a trick I am missing to speed it up by at least 5-6 times if not 8 times using 8 cores? Thanks!

I have looked at other R parallel links but could not find an answer that will explain what I am doing wrong.

---

```
library(parallel)

library(lsa)

cosine.par <- function(cl, vecA, matB){

  Blist <- lapply(c(1:ncol(matB)), function(ii)  as.vector(matB[,ii,drop=FALSE]))

  #print("Parallel Call")

  ans <- clusterApply(cl, Blist, cosine, vecA)

 do.call(rbind, ans)

}

k=500

vecA=c(1:k)

matB=matrix(rep(c(1:k),1000000), ncol=1000000)

nc <- detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost", nc))

print(paste(format(Sys.time(), 
                   "%a %b %d %X %Y %Z")))

cosine.par(cl, vecA, matB)

print(paste(format(Sys.time(), 
                   "%a %b %d %X %Y %Z")))

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: What CPU usage did you observe? If the processes differ in computation time, you may  want to try `clusterApplyLB` which does load balancing. I also found that, on some machines with Intel CPUs, it was necessary to turn off Hyper Threading to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: I have 8 core Mac running 2.4gz Intel. Top command showed about 25-30% cpu of each of the 8 R processes and overall total utilization was 30% too. I was expecting 90% for each core amounting to close to 750% total which is not atypical in obviosuly parallel applications like this one

Comment: What about memory? If the individual CPU loads are only 25%, it might be that `cosine` is merely memory- rather than CPU-intensive. Like I said, if you really need the computing power, then try disabling HT. A word of caution, however, having all cores 100% busy might render your system inoperable until calculations are finished (without HT).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're executing a million tiny tasks, which can be extremely inefficient. In this case, you can use the `parApply` function:

```
cosine.par <- function(cl, vecA, matB) {
  r <- parApply(cl, matB, 2, cosine, vecA)
  dim(r) <- c(length(r), 1)
  r
}
```

This runs much faster for me than your original code, but you will still run into problems when the matrix becomes too big for your machine.

Since you're using a Mac, you could also try using `mclapply`:

```
cosine.mc <- function(nc, vecA, matB) {
  r <- unlist(mclapply(1:nc, function(i) {
    n <- ceiling(ncol(matB) / nc)
    j <- (n * (i - 1)) + 1
    k <- min(n * i, ncol(matB))
    apply(matB[,seq(j, k), drop=FALSE], 2, cosine, vecA)
  }, mc.cores=nc))
  dim(r) <- c(length(r), 1)
  r
}
```

Although this is quite efficient, I have run into the following error when operating on large matrices with `mclapply`.

```
Error in mcfork() : 
  unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory
```

If you get this error, you will either have to use less memory, use fewer workers, or add more memory to your computer.

Comment: Excellent! What's the last  dim(r) <- c(length(r), 1) for?

Comment: @WDTWDT It's optional, but it sets the "dim" attribute in the same way that your example does. If you leave it out, the result will be a vector rather than a matrix with one column.

Comment: While parApply works well, I observed the CPU usage of each of the 8 R processes during execution and only two processes reach 90% level CPU while other just stay at 0%. How to make best use of all 8 cores?

Comment: @WDTWDT Since you're using a Mac, you will probably do better using mclapply.