# Cosine distance matrix as a function of Euclidean distance matrix in R, and applications to binary vectors

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

I was reading about the Cosine distance, and looking for a method to calculate it in R.

I did not find it, but from [its description in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) it seemed pretty straightforward to write it as a function of the simple Euclidean distance matrix one can obtain from `dist`.

If the input matrix has *row* vectors, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578876/which-is-the-best-way-to-parallelize-cosine-distance), the function is:

```
Cosine_dist_rows <- function(m) {
  0.5*(dist(m/sqrt(rowSums(m^2)),method="euclidean"))^2
}
```

If it has *column* vectors:

```
Cosine_dist_cols <- function(m) {
  0.5*(dist(t(m)/sqrt(colSums(m^2)),method="euclidean"))^2
}
```

I tested it with the data from the example I linked above, and it seemed to work (it gave a near-zero difference between the similarity matrix from `lsa` and 1 minus the distance matrix from the above code).

Does anybody know if:

1. using R's own `dist` to compute a Euclidean distance matrix is efficient, or instead suffers from memory or speed limitations?
2. doing the above additional calculations on the resulting `dist` object is particularly costly?
3. this could be done better / more efficiently when the input matrix `m` is binary (and sparse)?

I'm asking because I might need to calculate cosine distance matrices from sets of 10^4-10^5 sparse binary vectors, and I suspect that going via the Euclidean distance when one has binary vectors is not the best idea.
Apart from using `m` instead of `m^2` in the `colSums/rowSums` computation, which is the same for binary vectors, I would not know what else could be done to make this more efficient.
I know that a `"binary"` method exists in `dist`, but that is what we usually refer to as "Tanimoto" distance, which has a different formula and can't easily be linked to the cosine distance (you would need to do matrix algebra, and then the advantage of using `dist` would be lost, I believe). Besides, I don't know if `"binary"` is much faster than `"euclidean"`.

Any idea?

Thanks!

PS
Here is an example of a matrix of 1000 sparse (row) vectors:

```
set.seed(123654)
dfu <- do.call(rbind, sapply(1:1000, function(i) {
  n <- ceiling(26/sample(2:52,1))
  data.frame("ID" = i, "F" = sample(LETTERS,size=n), stringsAsFactors = F)
}, simplify = F))
m <- xtabs(~ID + F, dfu, sparse = T)
```

Comment: Calculation of `dist` can make use of openBLAS or the Intel MKL, which can make quite a difference in performance. Memory requirements are still quite high. In principle, you could use something like `wordspace::dist.matrix(m, method = "cosine", as.dist = TRUE,  byrow = FALSE)` (or byrow=TRUE, depending on what you are after).

Comment: Thank you @user12728748. However, this command gives me the angle in degrees between the two vectors, and it takes longer than my functions based on `dist`. If I run it with `convert=FALSE` it is indeed quite a bit faster than `dist`, but it gives me a full similarity matrix (parameter `as.dist=TRUE` is not usable in that case), which I then have to subtract from 1 and convert with R's own `as.dist`. So yes, while it might be a bit better in terms of speed, it seems quite demanding in terms of memory. I'll give it a try!